# PC can not boot from HDD, buffer I/O error

Tags: hard-drive, boot

Since last two days, the HDD was working kind of slowly. After a machine reboot, PC can't boot from it. I have dualboot setup with ArchLinux and Windows 10. Now only the motherboard logo is shown, no grub menu. If I boot from a ArchLinux USB drive the following messages are shown at boot time and mounting time:

```
[sdb] No Caching mode page found
[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seq 1 prio class 0
Buffer I/O error on sdb, logical block 0, async page read
```

The disk can be mounted, files can be read but the operations are slow with those above errors. What should I do now? I will be copying the data to a new drive. Can this faulty HDD be revived? Also please provide any explanation about the cause of this issue.

Comment: Check the SMART data of the disk. To me it seems to be failing, so get the data off it asap.

Comment: Data was backed up. Now that drive does not work (error SRST failed). Is it possible to use/fix that failed drive as previous?

Comment: Checking the SMART data of the disk will give the answer.