# Missing Keystrokes on Asus BR1100F running Debian 10/11

Tags: debian, keyboard, asus, keystrokes

I have successfully installed Debian on the notebook following the instructions here: [128GB eMMC drive on ASUS laptop - unable to format to ext4](https://superuser.com/questions/1688659/128gb-emmc-drive-on-asus-laptop-unable-to-format-to-ext4). There is no desktop environment, console only. Everything goes smooth and the OS boots fine. However, there are a LOT of missed keystrokes. I have attempted to adjust repeat and delay settings with kdbrate but nothing seemed to help. The most significant issue is not being able to login since the missed keystrokes lead to the user entering an incorrect password. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have found the solution. You need to do a complete power drain. First power the machine down and remove the power cable. Then remove the 9 screws from the bottom of the case (two are covered with screw caps). Use a case tool to remove the keyboard. Then remove the battery cable only, the battery can stay in the machine. There is a good tear down video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6lysjmaBSA. Now, with the battery still disconnected and the power cord removed, hold down the power button for 30 seconds. Finally, put it all back together and boot the machine. The keyboard should now work without issue.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: Rather than "a complete power drain", what you did is known as a BIOS reset.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I didn't realize this reset the BIOS. In my experience (mostly desktops and servers), this sequence drained all of the capacitors on the board, which is why I mentioned a "power drain".